# Pandas: Converting to numeric, creating NaNs when necessary

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a column in a dataframe that has some numbers and some non-numbers

```
>> df['foo']
0       0.0
1     103.8
2     751.1
3       0.0
4       0.0
5         -
6         -
7       0.0
8         -
9       0.0
Name: foo, Length: 9, dtype: object
```

How can I convert this column to `np.float`, and have everything else that is not float convert it to `NaN`?

When I try:

```
>> df['foo'].astype(np.float)
```

or

```
>> df['foo'].apply(np.float)
```

I get `ValueError: could not convert string to float: -`

Comment: For a more comprehensive explanation of `pd.to_numeric` along with its applications, please take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47942854/4909087).

Answer (score 78, accepted):

In pandas `0.17.0` [`convert_objects`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects.html) raises a warning:

> FutureWarning: convert_objects is deprecated.  Use the data-type
>   specific converters pd.to_datetime, pd.to_timedelta and pd.to_numeric.

You could use [`pd.to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) method and apply it for the dataframe with arg `coerce`.

```
df1 = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, args=('coerce',))
```

or maybe more appropriately:

```
df1 = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

**EDIT**

The above method is only valid for pandas version >= `0.17.0`,  from [docs what's new in pandas 0.17.0](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#other-enhancements):

> pd.to_numeric is a new function to coerce strings to numbers (possibly with coercion) [(GH11133)](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/11133)

Comment: Fingers crossed this comes back, it was a great silver bullet.

Comment: 'module' object has no attribute 'to_numeric' ?

Comment: show edited version, it's only available from `0.17.0` pandas version

Answer (score 35):

Use the [`convert_objects`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects.html) Series method (and `convert_numeric`):

```
In [11]: s
Out[11]: 
0    103.8
1    751.1
2      0.0
3      0.0
4        -
5        -
6      0.0
7        -
8      0.0
dtype: object

In [12]: s.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
Out[12]: 
0    103.8
1    751.1
2      0.0
3      0.0
4      NaN
5      NaN
6      0.0
7      NaN
8      0.0
dtype: float64
```

*Note: this is also available as a DataFrame method.*

Comment: "Attempt to infer better dtype for object columns" is basically a magic bullet... (and it does dates too.)

Comment: @delgadom suprisingly there isn't a "cleaning" section in the [10 minute tutorial](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html). I need to finish up my book :)

Comment: It's depreciated unfortunately :/

Answer (score 30):

You can simply use `pd.to_numeric` and setting error to `coerce` without using `apply`

```
df['foo'] = pd.to_numeric(df['foo'], errors='coerce')
```

Answer (score 11):

First replace all the string values with `None`, to mark them as missing values and then convert it to float.

```
df['foo'][df['foo'] == '-'] = None
df['foo'] = df['foo'].astype(float)
```

Comment: Thanks! Good and simple.

Comment: Simple and works much better than the previous suggestions.