# Pandas ".convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)" deprecated

Tags: python, pandas

I have this line in my code which converts my data to numeric...

```
data["S1Q2I"] = data["S1Q2I"].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
```

The thing is that now the new pandas release (0.17.0) said that this function is deprecated..
This is the error:

```
FutureWarning: convert_objects is deprecated.  
Use the data-type specific converters pd.to_datetime, 
pd.to_timedelta and pd.to_numeric. 
data["S3BD5Q2A"] = data["S3BD5Q2A"].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
```

So, I went to the new documentation and I couldn't find any examples of how to use the new function to convert my data...

It only says this:

> "DataFrame.convert_objects has been deprecated in favor of type-specific functions pd.to_datetime, pd.to_timestamp and pd.to_numeric (new in 0.17.0) (GH11133)."

Any help would be nice!

Comment: You mean [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html#pandas.to_numeric)? What are you expecting this to do/not do?

Comment: It's just this: `data['S1Q2I'] = pd.to_numeric(data['S1Q2I'])`

Comment: Thanks! Now I understood!!

Comment: What if I want the entire DataFrame converted if it can be?  .convert_objects will act on a DataFrame, but .to_numeric only acts on a Series.

Comment: Same request.  How do you convert an entire DataFrame ?

Comment: The newly preferred methods simply do not capture the functionality of `.convert_objects`, which can _infer_ datatypes. This is CRUCIAL if you don't know in advance the types of your columns.

Comment: "The newly preferred methods simply do not capture the functionality of .convert_objects" is there an alternative non-deprecated method?

Comment: data["S1Q2I"] = data["S1Q2I"].astype(int) did not work?

Answer (score 22):

As explained by @EvanWright in the comments,

```
data['S1Q2I'] = pd.to_numeric(data['S1Q2I'])
```

is now the prefered way of converting types. A detailed explanation in of the change can be found in the github PR [GH11133](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/11133).

Answer (score 10):

You can effect a replacement using apply as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33795876/188963). An example would be:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> a = pd.DataFrame([{"letter":"a", "number":"1"},{"letter":"b", "number":"2"}])
>>> a.dtypes
letter    object
number    object
dtype: object
>>> b = a.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors="ignore")
>>> b.dtypes
letter    object
number     int64
dtype: object
>>>
```

But it sucks in two ways:

1. You have to use apply rather than a non-native dataframe method
2. You have to copy to another dataframe--can't be done in place. So much for use with "big data."

I'm not really loving the direction pandas is going. I haven't used R data.table much, but so far it seems superior.

I think a data table with native, in-place type conversion is pretty basic for a competitive data analysis framework.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on which version of Pandas......
if you have Pandas's version 0.18.0 
this type will work ........

```
df['col name'] = df['col name'].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

another versions ........

```
df['col name']=df.col name .astype(float)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you convert all columns to numeric at once, this code may work.

```
data = data.apply(pd.to_numeric, axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get it to apply correctly to a particular variable name in a dataframe without having to copy into a different dataframe like this:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> a = pd.DataFrame([{"letter":"a", "number":"1"},{"letter":"b", "number":"2"}])
>>> a.dtypes
letter    object
number    object
dtype: object
>>> a['number'] = a['number'].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
>>> a.dtypes
letter    object
number     int64
dtype: object
```

An example based on the original question above would be something like:

```
data['S1Q2I'] = data['S1Q2I'].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

This works the same way as your original:

```
data['S1Q2I'] = data['S1Q2I'].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
```

in my hands, anyway....

This doesn't address the point abalter made about inferring datatypes which is a little above my head I'm afraid!

Comment: Ahh I've just read the discussion [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11221) and appreciate the limitations, now. Most annoying. But, if you have  a particular dataframe column you want to convert, this is how you could do it.