# convert entire pandas dataframe to integers in pandas (0.17.0)

Tags: python, pandas

My question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33126477/pandas-convert-objectsconvert-numeric-true-deprecated), but I need to convert my entire dataframe instead of just a series. The `to_numeric` function only works on one series at a time and is not a good replacement for the deprecated `convert_objects` command. Is there a way to get similar results to the `convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)` command in the new pandas release?

Thank you Mike Müller for your example. `df.apply(pd.to_numeric)` works very well if the values can all be converted to integers. What if in my dataframe I had strings that could not be converted into integers? 
Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ints': ['3', '5'], 'Words': ['Kobe', 'Bryant']})
df.dtypes
Out[59]: 
Words    object
ints     object
dtype: object
```

Then I could run the deprecated function and get:

```
df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
df.dtypes
Out[60]: 
Words    object
ints      int64
dtype: object
```

Running the `apply` command gives me errors, even with try and except handling.

Answer (score 146, accepted):

### All columns convertible

You can apply the function to all columns:

```
df.apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

Example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['1', '2'], 
                       'b': ['45.8', '73.9'],
                       'c': [10.5, 3.7]})

>>> df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 3 columns):
a    2 non-null object
b    2 non-null object
c    2 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1), object(2)
memory usage: 64.0+ bytes

>>> df.apply(pd.to_numeric).info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 3 columns):
a    2 non-null int64
b    2 non-null float64
c    2 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(2), int64(1)
memory usage: 64.0 bytes
```

### Not all columns convertible

`pd.to_numeric` has the keyword argument `errors`:

> ```
>   Signature: pd.to_numeric(arg, errors='raise')
>   Docstring:
>   Convert argument to a numeric type.
>
> Parameters
> ----------
> arg : list, tuple or array of objects, or Series
> errors : {'ignore', 'raise', 'coerce'}, default 'raise'
>     - If 'raise', then invalid parsing will raise an exception
>     - If 'coerce', then invalid parsing will be set as NaN
>     - If 'ignore', then invalid parsing will return the input
> ```

Setting it to `ignore` will return the column unchanged if it cannot be converted into a numeric type.

As pointed out by  Anton Protopopov, the most elegant way is to supply `ignore` as keyword argument to `apply()`:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'ints': ['3', '5'], 'Words': ['Kobe', 'Bryant']})
>>> df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore').info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 2 columns):
Words    2 non-null object
ints     2 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 48.0+ bytes
```

My previously suggested way, using [partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html?highlight=partial#functools.partial) from the module `functools`, is more verbose:

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'ints': ['3', '5'], 
                       'Words': ['Kobe', 'Bryant']})
>>> df.apply(partial(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')).info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 2 columns):
Words    2 non-null object
ints     2 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 48.0+ bytes
```

Comment: I think, the most elegant way to set this argument in the `apply` as keywarg: `df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')` should work fine.

Comment: `to_numeric` does not do commas.

Comment: To get only integer numeric columns in the end, as the question stated, loop through all columns: `for i in df.columns:
     try:
        df[[i]] = df[[i]].astype(int)
    except:
        pass`

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer with pd.to_numeric() converts to float, as soon as it is needed. Reading the question in detail, it is about converting any numeric column to *integer*.
That is why the accepted answer needs a loop over all columns to convert the numbers to int in the end.

Just for completeness, this is even possible without pd.to_numeric(); of course, this is not recommended:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['1', '2'], 
                   'b': ['45.8', '73.9'],
                   'c': [10.5, 3.7]})

for i in df.columns:
    try:
        df[[i]] = df[[i]].astype(float).astype(int)
    except:
        pass

print(df.dtypes)
```

Out:

```
a    int32
b    int32
c    int32
dtype: object
```

**EDITED:**
Mind that this not recommended solution is unnecessarily complicated; `pd.to_numeric()` can simply use the keyword argument `downcast='integer'` to force integer as output, thank you for the comment. This is then still missing in the accepted answer, though.

**News again**
From a comment by user [Gary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1054260/gary), it turns out that "as of pandas 2.0.1, if input series contains empty string or `None` then the resulting dtype will still be float even when using `downcast='integer'`". That would mean that the first answer with `.astype(float).astype(int)` is alive again if you want to be sure to get only integers.

Comment: If all of the 'numbers' are formatted as integers (i.e. `'5'`, not `'5.0'`) then the keyword argument `downcast='integer'` can be used in the `to_numeric` function to force the integer type: In this example ```df.apply(pd.to_numeric, downcast='integer')``` will return column `a` as integer

Comment: Note that as of pandas 2.0.1, if input series contains empty string or `None` then the resulting dtype will still be float even when using `downcast='integer'`.

Answer (score 1):

`apply()` the   `pd.to_numeric` **with** `errors='ignore'` **and** assign it back to the DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ints': ['3', '5'], 'Words': ['Kobe', 'Bryant']})
print ("Orig: \n",df.dtypes)

df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')
print ("\nto_numeric: \n",df.dtypes)

df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')
print ("\nto_numeric with assign: \n",df.dtypes)
```

Output:

```
Orig: 
 ints     object
Words    object
dtype: object

to_numeric: 
 ints     object
Words    object
dtype: object

to_numeric with assign: 
 ints      int64
Words    object
dtype: object
```

Comment: It goes without saying that you need to reassign the df if you want to save the changes. This should have been just a comment under the accepted solution.

Answer (score 1):

you can use df.astype() to convert the series to desired datatype.

For example: 
my_str_df = [['20','30','40']]

then:
my_int_df = my_str_df['column_name'].astype(int) # this will be the int type

Comment: Downvote. The question was about a dataframe, not a series, and you do not explain how you would change a whole dataframe that also has float columns of type string like '45.8'.