# Variable inflation factor not working with dataframes python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, statistics, statsmodels

I have a dataset of `(1460, 76)` size. It's currently in pandas Dataframe, It has all sorts of datatypes: `int, float, object`. I'm trying to run `VIF` function on this dataframe to get correlation in my variables but, it's throwing this error:

```
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

VIF Code:

```
vif = [variance_inflation_factor(df.values, i) for i in range(df.shape[1])]
print(vif)
```

What could be the reason, is it because I have strings in my data?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like some of your data is stored as strings instead of numeric data types. Try using [pandas.to_numeric](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) on your data frame.

[Example applying to_numeric to an entire data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34844711/convert-entire-pandas-dataframe-to-integers-in-pandas-0-17-0/34844867)

Comment: Yes, I do string data. Is there a way around?