# Changing type of entire dataframe using Lambda Function

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, data-analysis

I'm trying to convert an entire dataframe into integer, i.e. all Variables to type(int), the data has NaNs present, so was going for pd.to_numeric and coercing the errors to NaN, where I can handle them later.

> But pd.to_numeric takes a list, tuple, 1-d array, or Series.

I can go on step by step by giving each column name and changing the type.
But is there any way to do that optimally in few lines?

I tried this, but getting error.

```
change = lambda x: pd.to_numeric(df_copy[x], errors='coerce')
df_copy = pd.DataFrame(map(change, x) for x in df_copy.columns)
```

Comment: This might help... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34844711/convert-entire-pandas-dataframe-to-integers-in-pandas-0-17-0

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this
`df_copy.apply(lambda x : pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce'))`

[[convert entire pandas dataframe to integers in pandas (0.17.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34844711/convert-entire-pandas-dataframe-to-integers-in-pandas-0-17-0])