# Check if a column contains object containing float values in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a column that contains object which contains float(like this "12.45"). How can I check if this column exists in panda data frame. I want to find this column first and convert all of it's values into float. In another words how can I look for the columns that have objects containing numeric values like floats "12.54". I do not want to look for the objects that contain non numeric values like "cat" or "dog"

for example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"column1":[ "12.44", "56.78", "45.87"],
    "column2":["cat", "dog", "horse"]})
```

I want to check if column1 exists in my columns in order to convert all of it's values to float

Comment: `df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors="ignore")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert entire pandas dataframe to integers in pandas (0.17.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34844711/convert-entire-pandas-dataframe-to-integers-in-pandas-0-17-0)

Comment: will try it thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) to try to convert the strings to numeric values.  Then, check for each element in the converted columns whether it is an instance of float type by using [`.applymap()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) and [`isinstance(x, float)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance).  Finally, check for any column value in a column is of type `float` by [`.any()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors="ignore").applymap(lambda x: isinstance(x, float), na_action='ignore').any()
```

**Result:**

```
column1     True
column2    False
dtype: bool
```

`True` value of `column1` corresponds to it has at least one element of type `float`

Actually, this solution can also check for individual elements whether of `float` type by removing the [`.any()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) at the end:

```
df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors="ignore").applymap(lambda x: isinstance(x, float), na_action='ignore')
```

Result:

```
   column1  column2
0     True    False
1     True    False
2     True    False
```

Comment: thank you for the answer!

Comment: @MZG  Let me know whether it works for you.  Thanks!

Comment: @MZG I've just edited of a part in addition to checking by column, it can also check for individual elements.  Take a look.

Comment: yea I saw that you edited. I tried that but solution from @ddejohn matched better with my code. thanks again for taking time and answering my question.

Comment: sure! I did that

Answer (score 0):

You can try to convert column by column and catch errors along the way. Columns that won't convert are unchanged because the exception is raised before the column is reassigned.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"column1":[ "12.44", "56.78", "45.87"],
    "column2":["cat", "dog", "horse"],
    "column3":["1", "2", "3"]})

for colname in df.columns:
    try:
        df[colname] = df[colname].astype('float')
        print(f"{colname} converted")
    except ValueError:
        print(f"{colname} failed")
    
print(df.dtypes)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but for this line : df[colname] = df[colname].astype('float') I still get this error "could not convert string to float"

Comment: Running this exact script works for me. That is the text of the `ValueError` which the code catches and ignores. Are you running it some other way, not in an try/except block?

Comment: I tried it in try except block same as your answer but in debugger I got error

Comment: @MZG - that's likely because of the debugger. You should be able to continue and go through the exception handler.