# Delete a line contains "?" in Python

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am operating the UCI data sets, some of them contains "?" in lines. For example:

```
56.0,1.0,2.0,130.0,221.0,0.0,2.0,163.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,7.0,0
58.0,1.0,2.0,125.0,220.0,0.0,0.0,144.0,0.0,0.4,2.0,?,7.0,0
57.0,0.0,2.0,130.0,236.0,0.0,2.0,174.0,0.0,0.0,2.0,1.0,3.0,1
38.0,1.0,3.0,138.0,175.0,0.0,0.0,173.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,?,3.0,0
```

I firstly use `numpy.loadtxt()` to load file, and try to delete the lines with "?" using `line.contains('?')`, but got error with the type.

Then I use `pandas.read_csv`, however, I still have no easy way to delete all lines contains a specific letter "?".

Is there any easy way to clean the data? I need a float type data file without any "?" in it. Thanks~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a small script to read the file line by line, and output "desirable" lines to a new file. Then operate on the cleaned data.

The way I would do it is with this:

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input():
    if '?' not in line:
        print line.strip() # to avoid adding new newlines
```

and run it in bash as follows

```
python script.py < dirty.txt > clean.txt
```

This uses stdin and stdout to process the file, and bash stdin/stdout redirects to read/write to/from files.

An alternative pure python solution:

```
input_file = 'dirty.txt'
output_file = 'clean.txt'

with open(input_file) as dirty:
    with open(output_file, 'w') as clean:
        for line in dirty:
            if '?' not in line:
                clean.write(line)
```

Comment: If bash can be used as opposed to python, the job could be accomplished with just: `grep -v "?" < dirty.txt > clean.txt`

Comment: I directly using `outfile.write(line)` after your code `if '?' not in line:`, and it is done. thank you .

Comment: Another concern: when I use `line.strip()`, I got a output without `\n`. So is it necessary to use `strip()` here?

Comment: @flyingmouse, when you print, it automatically adds `\n`. When writing to file, you should remove the `.strip()` as `write` doesn't add `\n` for you.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with Pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
df = df.replace('?', pd.np.nan)
df = df.dropna()
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have all others numbers you could use answer for [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18434208/pandas-converting-to-numeric-creating-nans-when-necessary/33795876?noredirect=1#comment55742429_33795876) question and then use `dropna` method
*that could be used only with pandas version >= `0.17.0`*:

```
df.apply(pd.to_numeric, args=('coerce',)).dropna()

In [247]: df
Out[247]:
   0   1   2    3    4   5   6    7   8    9   10   11  12  13
0  56   1   2  130  221   0   2  163   0  0.0   1  0.0   7   0
1  58   1   2  125  220   0   0  144   0  0.4   2    ?   7   0
2  57   0   2  130  236   0   2  174   0  0.0   2  1.0   3   1
3  38   1   3  138  175   0   0  173   0  0.0   1    ?   3   0

In [248]: df.apply(pd.to_numeric, args=('coerce',)).dropna()
Out[248]:
   0   1   2    3    4   5   6    7   8   9   10  11  12  13
0  56   1   2  130  221   0   2  163   0   0   1   0   7   0
2  57   0   2  130  236   0   2  174   0   0   2   1   3   1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use pandas [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) you can tell it to treat `?` entries as `NaN` and then call [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
In [9]:
import io
import pandas as pd
​
t="""56.0,1.0,2.0,130.0,221.0,0.0,2.0,163.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,7.0,0
58.0,1.0,2.0,125.0,220.0,0.0,0.0,144.0,0.0,0.4,2.0,?,7.0,0
57.0,0.0,2.0,130.0,236.0,0.0,2.0,174.0,0.0,0.0,2.0,1.0,3.0,1
38.0,1.0,3.0,138.0,175.0,0.0,0.0,173.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,?,3.0,0"""
​
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), na_values=['?'], header=None)
df

Out[9]:
   0   1   2    3    4   5   6    7   8    9   10  11  12  13
0  56   1   2  130  221   0   2  163   0  0.0   1   0   7   0
1  58   1   2  125  220   0   0  144   0  0.4   2 NaN   7   0
2  57   0   2  130  236   0   2  174   0  0.0   2   1   3   1
3  38   1   3  138  175   0   0  173   0  0.0   1 NaN   3   0

In [10]:    
df.dropna()

Out[10]:
   0   1   2    3    4   5   6    7   8   9   10  11  12  13
0  56   1   2  130  221   0   2  163   0   0   1   0   7   0
2  57   0   2  130  236   0   2  174   0   0   2   1   3   1
```

So in your case the following should work:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('dirty.txt', header=None, na_values=['?']).dropna()
df.to_csv('clean.txt', header=False, index=False)
```