# Convert non-numbers in dataframe to NaN (numpy)?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How to convert non-numbers in `DataFrame` to `NaN (numpy)`? For example, here is a `DataFrame`:

```
a    b
--------
10   ...
4    5
...  6
```

How to covert it to:

```
a    b
--------
10   NaN
4    5
NaN  6
```

Comment: Should be marked as duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18434208/pandas-converting-to-numeric-creating-nans-when-necessary

Answer (score 10, accepted):

IIUC you can just do

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce') )
```

This will force the duff values to `NaN`, note that the presence of `NaN` will change the dtype to `float` as `NaN` cannot be represented by `int`

```
In [6]:
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
df

Out[6]:
      a    b
0  10.0  NaN
1   4.0  5.0
2   NaN  6.0
```

The `lambda` isn't necessary but it's more readable IMO

Comment: I like `df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')`  `apply` will pass the `errors` parameter.

Comment: is lambda necessary?

Comment: @piRSquared sure, have posted, It's a habit of mine

Comment: @AsheKetchum no, it's not necessary but it's a habit of mine for readability

Comment: @EdChum That is true :)

Comment: @AsheKetchum the `lambda` is just syntax.  You would need it, if `apply` didn't pass arguments to the function being passed.  And I agree with EdChum... the lambda makes it more obvious what is happening.

Answer (score 4):

You can can also `stack` then `unstack` the dataframe

```
pd.to_numeric(df.stack(), errors='coerce').unstack()

      a    b
0  10.0  NaN
1   4.0  5.0
2   NaN  6.0
```

Comment: what is the advantage?