# DataFrame object type column to int or float error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 20 entries, 0 to 19
Data columns (total 7 columns):
Borough        20 non-null object
Indian         20 non-null object
Pakistani      20 non-null object
Bangladeshi    20 non-null object
Chinese        20 non-null object
Other_Asian    20 non-null object
Total_Asian    20 non-null object
dtypes: object(7)
```

Only 'Borough' column is string and others should be int or float.
I am trying to convert using astype(int). I have tried all the options mentioned on the internet but still getting error.

```
df_LondonEthnicity['Indian'] = df_LondonEthnicity['Indian'].astype(int)
```

Errors is :

> invalid literal for int() with base 10:

I also tried

```
df_LondonEthnicity['Indian'] = df_LondonEthnicity.astype({'Indian': int}).dtypes
```

I also tried

```
cols = ['Indian', 'Pakistani', 'Bangladeshi', 'Chinese', 'Other_Asian', 'Total_Asian']  

for col in cols:  # Iterate over chosen columns
  df_LondonEthnicity[col] = pd.to_numeric(df_LondonEthnicity[col])
```

Also tried converting got string and then to float

I'd appreciate some help on this. Thanks

Comment: can you provide sample data of `df_LondonEthnicity` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18434208/pandas-converting-to-numeric-creating-nans-when-necessary. `pd.to_numeric` is the correct tool for conversion. If `pandas` didn't automatically parse the column as a numeric dtype then `astype` won't help. `to_numeric `allows you to convert all non-numeric data to `NaN`

Comment: what do you have in `df_LondonEthnicity['Indian']` ? if there is empty string or string with text instead number then you can't convert it

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, you need to use the `to_numeric` function.

What the error means is that value you are trying to convert contains characters other than `0-9` (base10).

So the options that you have is either use `pd.to_numeric` and have all the non-conforming values to be `NaN` or to convert it somehow.

So say you have a dataframe like this.

```py
>>> df
       X
0    123
1   123,
2    200
3  200.1
```

---

Using `pd.to_numeric` will such an output. But the values are floats.

```py
>>> pd.to_numeric(df.X, errors='coerce')
0    123.0
1      NaN
2    200.0
3    200.1
Name: X, dtype: float64
```

---

Other option is to convert it somehow like this.

```py
>>> df.X.str.extract(r'([\d]+)').astype(int)
     0
0  123
1  123
2  200
3  200
```

Comment: Thanks. All the columns except 'Borough' contains numbers and hence should be int or float so that I can do some mathematical calculations. I am scraping the information for the webpage.          

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethnic_groups_in_London'

# Connect to the URL
response = requests.get(url)

# Parse HTML and save to BeautifulSoup object
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")  # This is beautiful soup object which has whole HTML text parsed

table = soup.find_all('table')[4] 
I tried your method and it converted all my data into NaN.

Comment: Got it.  My numbers were in the format 12,456. I have removed the comma and now its working.  Thanks for your help.